# Foursquare API for rich media

Tags: foursquare, ads

We would like to build a rich media ad and would like to apply foursquare functionality.

Is foursquare API  now available for rich media integration?

Comment: What do you understand by the term "rich media integration"? Can you explain what you are planning to do? What kind of ad are you going to create?

Comment: Hi Charles. Thanks for your feedback. Actually the ad we are planning to create is a simple 975x550 expanding ad unit. Basically it only includes video, video buttons. And we want to include this functionality in the ad. Is there an API we can use for adobe flash AS3?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [REST API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/), and even a [client library for ActionScript 3](https://github.com/ludicast/foursquare).